# TFS select all value in custom control multi select

Tags: tfs

I have a custom control Multi select.
I want to give ability select the all value by select one check box.
[image]

Something like this. When I'll select "all os" it'll be save the value like was select one by one .

Answer (score 1):

This control is [open sourced on Codeplex](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/). Feel free to add this ability to the control.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer.
This one give me a half solution. i want to select "all" or "un-check all " and it'll select the all value or diselect